# Sketch Plugin Develop : Is there an API for Sketch to unlock the size of MSBitmapLayer?

Tags: plugins, sketch-3, sketchapp, cocoascript

The unlock size button in Sketh App

[image]

I can click this button to unlock the size of a layer in Sketch App.
And then I can change the width/height ratio of the image.
But I want my Sketch plugin to do this job instead of using my hand to click the button.
Is there an API for Sketch to unlock the size of `MSBitmapLayer`?

I've tried "`[layer setIsLocked:false]`", but it's not about the size lock.

Thank you very much.

Comment: while browsing through the header files I stumbled upon a boolean function called "constrainProportions" in MSLayer. I suppose it might be what you are looking for ... but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular function you are looking for is 
setConstrainProportions()

Here is an example for you, It might help you in understanding it

```
function toggleConstrainProportions(context) {
  var doc = context.document
  var selection = context.selection

  // Toggles the currently selected item(s) 'Constrain Proportions'setting

  for (var i = 0; i < [selection count]; i++) {
    var s = [selection objectAtIndex: i]
    s.frame().setConstrainProportions(!s.constrainProportions())
  }
}
```

Hope this is helpful :)